# What is the purpose of the following service in oracle OracleSchedulerXE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, database-administration

I have a question regarding the purpose of some service in sql. What does the process, the purpose of them.

OracleSchedulerXE
OracleORADB19Home1MTSRecoveryService
OracleOraDB19home1TNSListner
OracleRemExecServiceV2
OracleServiceXE
OracleVSSWriter

I tried to find something about OracleSchedurXE but I did nt find anithing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If I Google any of the service names, I get back several pages that go into detail about what they do.

- [OracleSchedulerXE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034) is used by Oracle for the `dbms_scheduler` package that lets you schedule jobs to run inside the database.
- [OracleORADB19Home1MTSRecoveryService](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e26104/recovery.htm#NTMTS136) is used for interacting with the Microsoft Transaction Server.  Most commonly, that is used to allow applications to manage distributed transactions that involve Oracle and other Windows services.
- [OracleOraDB19home1TNSListner](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/listenercfg.htm#NETAG010) is used for the TNS listener.
  That's the process that allows users to connect to the database from remote machines.
- [OracleRemExecServiceV2](http://joordsblog.vandenoord.eu/2012/03/oracleremexecservice-available-windows.html) is a service used by the Oracle Universal Installer during installation that will be removed once you reboot after a successful install.
- OracleServiceXE is the service that actually runs the Oracle database
- [OracleVSSWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/vss.htm#:%7E:text=A%20VSS%20writer%20is%20an,instance%20and%20other%20VSS%20components.) is a service that interacts with the Windows Volume Shadow Copy service to ensure that backups see files in a consistent state.